# iOSK: What kind of data type is ABRecordRef?

Tags: ios, database, ios5, sqlite

I want to save an ABRecordRef to a SQLite3 DB. Whst type of data type do I use for a SQLite field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the individual components of the address and save them as text strings.

**Update:**

If you just want an identifier to the ABRecord, retrieve the `ABRecordID` via `ABRecordGetRecordID` and save that as a numeric value in SQLite.

Comment: Yes but I want to store the ABRecordRef in addition to some computed data. Maybe I may want to use ABRecordID instead but I still need a way to store it into an SQLite database

Comment: That makes sense. It's just that SQLite3 is fairly primitive in terms of the sorts of data types that can be stored. See [Datatypes in SQLite 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Simple numeric and text fields are fine. Or you can use the blob data type for NSData (which I doubt is applicable in this situation, but you can use that for things like images or the like, though it's not terribly efficient).

Comment: Given that ABRecordID is a int32_t, I would have thought that you could store that pretty easily.

Comment: @CocoaDev `ABRecordRef` is a `CFTypeRef`, which is a `const void *`, which undoubtedly is not a good candidate. It looks like `ABRecordId` (retrieved by `ABRecordGetRecordID`) is the way to go.